How to programmatically add a frame in LibreOffice Writer?
How do you programmatically (in content.xml ??) add to a odt document a frame of style "MyFrameStyle" with content x ?
context: pandoc lua filter

Has this anything in common with your other question? Please [edit] to clarify. You might also add a [mre].

The other question was asking about adding a custom-style, this is asking about adding a frame tag. The solution to both problems is in this pandoc discussion thread: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/discussions/10307
